# MS Blend preview Designer Catastrophic failure

Tags: expression-blend, silverlight-5.0

I know this kind of problem must be posted on microsoft support forums, so did I , but still didn't get answer. maybe someone here may know what causes this problem.
So.. i have strange problem with blend for silverlight 5. I created new blank new project , everytime i try to add control (button, or textbox or something else), I' getting that error exception. here is screenshot:
[image]

If i leave control Content property blank string "" error disappears.

here is list of related software installed on my computer:

- VS 2012 premium

  MS blend preview for silverlight 5 version 4.1.20402.0

  Silverlight 5 Toolkit - December 2011

  Silverlight Developer x64

  Silverlight 5

  OS is Windows 7 x64 enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Try updating with the latest CTP update (CTP update 3) for Visual Studio 2012, and use the Blend that comes with Visual Studio after the CTP, and not the Preview Version.

The CTP can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36539

Comment: ok, I'll try download those update. Actually i updated my VS 2012 already, but I'm not sure if it was same update. p.s. on windows 7 VS2012 blend doesn't work, it requires blend preview download