# Cannot add any control on the workspace [Catastrophic failure]

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

There is a problem with my developer machine when I created a project on Silverlight. At the moment I add a control on the grid it shows an exception and the layout is destroyed.

**Here are the steps to replicate the problem.**

- Create New Silverlight Application
- Uncheck Host the Silverlight application in a new Web site
- Choose Silverlight Version: Silverlight 5

and it successfully creates blank project file

[image]

When I tried to add this code inside `Grid`

```
<Button Content="Button" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="67,125,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

It generates an exception: see below

[image]

[**>> Click here to see FULL SCREEN Image <<**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16021179/Screenshot%20for%20StackOverflow/FullA.jpg)

The two StackTraces Generated:

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(DependencyObject obj, String name)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_UpdateLayout(UIElement element)
```

and

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

I have already rebuilt the project but it seems not working. It stills show the exception. But at the moment I remove the `Button` inside the `Grid` it returns on the previous blank project. I just can't add any controls inside the `Grid`. What did I missed here? *I'm new with this one. It's my first time to create silverlight project file.*

Did anybody here experienced the same error message?

If this question has been asked before kindly help me redirect on that page because I can't find it.

---

By the way, here's what inside my development machine:

- Windows 7 Ultimate (x64)
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 V 11.0.50.727.1 RTMREL
- Silverlight Developer Runtime 5.1.20125.0 (x64)
- Silverlight SDK 5.0.61118.0

---

**UPDATE 1**

I tried doing it in `Blend` but still the same error was thrown,

[image]

Comment: I found a question related to this but still not being answered. [Here's the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877186/ms-blend-preview-designer-catastrophic-failure)

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you follow the same steps on another machine? If not, it may be worth reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have already reinstalled everything. I was wondering maybe I have missed somthing on my machine.